# Is it bad to keep a server client response connection open and alive in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it a bad idea or just bad performance overall to keep a node.js server to client connection open? (not using x.end(); ).

I'm trying to play around with node.js, getting a hang of it and this is what I'm trying to do:
Use the node.js executable file as an open handle for multi-clients to communicate with each other, what I've done so far just to test around is to create an HTTP server which just for the sense, have an interval of 5000ms writing "test". And since having this idea of communicating forever with the client until they disconnect, I can't see myself ending the handle.

```
var http = require("http"),
    date = require("./modules/date.js");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log("[" + date.currentTimestamp() + "] Receiving a connection from " + server.address().address);

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("Hello World!<br>Current time: " + date.currentTimestamp() + "<br>Current url: " + request.url);
    setInterval(function() {
        response.write(" test");
    }, 5000);
}).listen(80);

console.log("[" + date.currentTimestamp() + "] Server has initialized.");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is not that bad, you just reinvented long polling :)
It is a pattern of server-client interactions that has been widely used for sending server events. That’s how it works:
1. Client subscribes for some event by connecting to the server.
2. Server keeps the connection open as long as possible
3. If the event fires while the connection is open, server responds with the event payload and metadata and closes the connection.
4. If no events fire, the connection is closed after some amount of time to avoid spending resources on inactive clients.
5. In the both cases client reconnects and expects further events.

[image]

Long polling was invented before websocket have been introduced. While websockets are designed just for long living client-server event exchange, long polling is more kinda a trick. The best idea is to use websocket for browsers that support it, and fall back to long polling for the ones that don’t. Some libraries like socket.io can do that automatically, btw.

Answer (score 4):

The HTTP protocol is a request-response paradigm. In a conversation, it would a person saying one thing and another responding. The code works, but the protocol is not being used the way it was designed. The better way to accomplish your goal is through using a [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). Websockets are designed to be kept open and transfer data back and forth for long lived connections.

Comment: Was going to mention the use of socket protocol is probably the best for management of what the OP is intending.